# IBObjects TIB_Grid and TIB_LookupCombo display problem

Tags: delphi-7

I use IBOjects in Delphi 7.
I read that LookupCombo can also be used within TIB_Grid.
I tried it and it doesn't work.
If anyone uses please help.

Detail Query Settings for LookupCombo:

- KeySource: dsPODetail
- KeyLinks: SITES.SITE = PO_DETAIL.PO_DET_SITE
- KeyLinksAutoDefine = true
- FetchWholeRows = true

LookupCombo Settings:

- DataSource: dsDetSite
- DisplayField: SITES.SITE
- Parent Control is a Grid (I checked on Object TreeView)

Grid Settings:

- DataSource : dsPODetail
- Ctl3DShadow : true
- ListBoxStyle = true
- StretchColumn : PO_DETAIL.PO_DET_ITEM_ID

All other values are the default.

I’ve read through everything I’ve found, but somehow it still doesn’t work and it would be a great help!

Thanks for All!

Comment: Ask Jason Wharton, he can help you fastly.

Comment: Please contact me directly at jason -AT- ibobjects -dot- com for support.

Comment: I wrote now : )